# Binding Different Enumerations in Scala

Tags: scala, enumeration

Scenario:
I have two Enumerations type: `Schema` and `Table`.

I want to bind every `Table` to a Specific `Schema`. So, actually I have implemented this:

```
object Table extends Enumeration {

  type Tabella = Value

  val TABLE1 = Value("TABLE1")
  val TABLE2 = Value("TABLE2")

  def getTable(myTable: Tabella): String = {
    myTable match {
      case Table.TABLE1  =>
        (Schema.SCHEMA1 + "." + Table.TABLE1)
      case Table.TABLE2  =>
        (Schema.SCHEMA1 + "." + Table.TABLE2)
    }
  }

}
```

and of course

```
object Schema extends Enumeration {

  type Schemi = Value
  val SCHEMA1 = Value("SCHEMA1")

}
```

Now everytime I need a table I call `Table.getTable(Table.TABLE1)`, but it's pretty awful code, I know. I'd like to improve this. Any Help?

I'd love to have some sort of `override def toString` in such way I just put my `Table.TABLE1` in code and return `SchemaName.TableName`, is this possible?

Comment: If you use case objects instead of Enumeration, you can define your own toString method. I'm not sure why it doesn't work with Enumerations -- I've tried. See here for an example (my own) of the technique: http://scalaprof.blogspot.com/2016/01/the-curious-incident-of-scala-enum.html

Comment: @Phasmid You can't because you'd have to override `Value`'s `toString`, not the enumeration's.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov so any advices?

Comment: @Phasmid Just follow Phasmid's approach. You can't change `Value'`s `toString` like this, but call it anything else.